# Performance improvement in unsigned integers function

Tags: performance, haskell

Any `Word32` number can be expressed as a linear combination of `Word8` numbers as follows:

```
x = a + b * 2^8 + c * 2^16 + d * 2^24
```

In other words, this is the representation of `x` in the base `2^8`. In order to obtain these factors, I implemented the following function:

```
word32to8 :: Word32 -> (Word8,Word8,Word8,Word8)
word32to8 n = (fromIntegral a,fromIntegral b,fromIntegral c,fromIntegral d)
  where
   (d,r1) = divMod n  (2^24)
   (c,r2) = divMod r1 (2^16)
   (b,a)  = divMod r2 (2^8)
```

It works properly but, since my program is using this function bunch of times, I thought that you guys can give me an idea of how to improve (if possible) the performance of this operation. Any minor improvement is good to me, either in time or space. To me, it looks like it is so simple that a performance improvement can't be achieved, but I still wanted to ask the question, just in case there is something I am missing.

By the way, I feel annoyed with all the repetitions of `fromIntegral`, but the conversion is necessary so the types can match.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a faster but perhaps less portable approach would be to use the `Storable` instance of `Word32` to access the underlying byte-level representation and then read all four bytes directly from that.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: that might be faster than 4 `divMod`s, but it's definitely not optimal.  Using `Storable` would mean allocating a new memory chunk, copying to it, and reading back.  @ertes's solution will avoid that extra allocation and copy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might get a major performance boost by defining a distinct type for the result, making use of a GHC extension and using bitwise operations instead:

```
data Split =
    Split {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8
          {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8
          {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8
          {-# UNPACK #-} !Word8

splitWord :: Word32 -> Split
splitWord x =
    Split (fromIntegral x)
          (fromIntegral (shiftR x 8))
          (fromIntegral (shiftR x 16))
          (fromIntegral (shiftR x 24))
```

This code is more than four times faster than your original function by using the following improvements:

- Instead of using the nonstrict tuple type I have defined a strict type `Split`.
- I have unpacked the fields of that type to get rid of most memory allocations and garbage collections.
- I have switched from `divMod` to `shiftR`.  You don't actually need to modulo operation, so I dropped it.

Another way to get a speed improvement is by not going through a concrete data type at all.  You probably want to perform calculations with the bytes, so we skip the step of storing and retrieving them.  Instead we pass the `splitWord` function a *continuation*:

```
splitWord :: (Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8 -> r) -> Word32 -> r
splitWord k x =
    k (fromIntegral x)
      (fromIntegral (shiftR x 8))
      (fromIntegral (shiftR x 16))
      (fromIntegral (shiftR x 24))
```

If you still want to save the bytes, you can just pass the `Split` constructor as the continuation:

```
splitWord Split 123456
```

But now you can also just perform the calculation you wanted to perform:

```
splitWord (\a b c d -> a + b + c + d) 123456
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that, even if you don't want to go all the way to bit-shifting, using `quot` is significantly faster than `divMod`.

Comment: According to my benchmark that isn't true.  But I know that it used to be true.  I'm on an i5 with GHC 7.6.1 and compiled with -O2.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Thank you. Everything worked just perfect. I didn't know about these _bit-wise_ operations. It looks like it is exactly what I needed. Also as a performance improvement. Then, I tried the `data` with strict unboxed fields. It did the code faster. And, finally, I applied the _continuation_ idea and worked awesomely.

Comment: @JohnL This is also a nice fact to know. Thank you!

Comment: @ertes: interesting.  I was under the impression this was still true with 7.6.1.  Perhaps only for signed types (which means they're different operations)?  I'll have to do some research on this.

Comment: @JohnL Yep, the difference is for signed types. For unsigned types (like `Word`), both families have the same semantics, so there is no special `divWord#` necessary, so both map to `quotWord# / remWord#`.

Comment: @JohnL However, in my case, when I only replaced `divMod` with `quotRem`, the resulting program was slightly faster. I am using GHC 7.4.2.